# Semi-transparent navbar with buttons in other color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar with

```
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
```

and I want to make one button in different color, but still semi-transparent.
The problem is that it overlays navbar background color, and I want to override it. 
I can set background color to buttons separately.

But in this case I don't know, how to set color to space between them.

http://www.bootply.com/5VQGFDHZfq

Comment: If my answer helped you, please select it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/06nHRbI1p5

HTML (add an `em` around the inside of the link):

```
<nav class="menu" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dp-white"><em>Dropdown white <span class="caret"></span></em></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown red <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

[image]

CSS:

```
.menu
{
  background-color:rgba(200, 20, 20, 0.7);
}

.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  background:transparent;
}

#dp-white {
  color: #000;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}


#dp-white em {
  color: #000;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  font-style:normal;
}

#dp-white:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:0;
  background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

#dp-white:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #026873;
   background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 50%, transparent 50%),
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.13) 50%, transparent 50%),
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.17) 50%),
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.19) 50%);
background-size: 13px, 29px, 37px, 53px;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-1;
}




body {
background-color: #026873;
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.07) 50%, transparent 50%),
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,.13) 50%, transparent 50%),
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.17) 50%),
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.19) 50%);
background-size: 13px, 29px, 37px, 53px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code, which you have provided in 'bootply'.
I have changed the css for menu class, like below. Is this your requirement. If not please let me know. I will do my best.

```
  .menu a{
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
```

Comment: No, sorry, that's not what i wanted. I wanted white button to be semi-transparent pure white, not mixed with semi-trasparent red of navbar like you see in my example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I got your requirement. You want to hide the complete red color semi transparent background for one button. And that button should be transparent enough, with out mixing with the actual red color. Let me think of the possibilities. If i got one. I will post it.